# Replace "templateUrl":path with "template":content for angular directives using gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

Looking for a gulp plugin to replace "templateUrl":path with "template":content for angular directives.

Templates can be large and writing all of them inline is not an option.

Using $templateCache is also not an option because it introduces extra dependency. Already tried ngHtml2js and similar plugins, didn't like it.

Comment: You can designate an HTML file's path..

Comment: Sure I can... Don't want to have separate template files for performance reasons (too many requests, in case someone is wondering).

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Ended up writing templates inline. 'templateUrl' seems like more cons than pros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin for Angular 2: https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template or this one for Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-plugin-angular-template-inline

Comment: Did you try it with angular v1 ?

Comment: Added both the plugins. I have only used the Angular 2 one.